# React-alert library does not seem to be re-rendering when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

So I'm trying to do error handling using a library called react-alert.

I'm using Axios as my REST handler. I created an action and a reducer, which are both working fine; saw my state update in my DevTools extension when I make a post request.

Here's my functional component called Alert.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Alert(props) {
  const alert = useAlert();
  const error = useSelector((state) => state.errors.errors);

  const [errorMSG, setERRORS] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error !== errorMSG) {
      setERRORS(error);
      alert.show(errorMSG);
    } else {
      alert.show("Welcome!");
    }
  }, [errorMSG]);

  return <Fragment />;
```

then I called it in my main App.js

```
//Main Imports
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// React Alert

import { Provider as AlertProvider } from "react-alert";
import AlertTemplate from "react-alert-template-basic";
import Alert from "./layout/Alert";

const alertOptions = {
  timeout: 3000,
  position: "top center",
};

//Components import
import Header from "./layout/Header";
import Dashboard from "./products/Dashboard";

//Redux import
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../store";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
          <Alert />
          <Fragment>
            <Header />
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <Dashboard />
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        </AlertProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

I do see the Welcome! when the app mounts, but when I have an error I see nothing. Could anyone help me find a solution to this; would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the point of having the error in the local state of the component?

Comment: Nothing. it was just me trying different things because I couldn't find a solution, but now I'm using the Redux store state and it works totally fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see "Welcome" because when your component mounts first time, it calls the `useEffect` hook. But the `useEffect` hook isn't getting triggered afterwards because of the wrong dependency item provided for the `useEffect`. You need to add `error` instead of `errorMSG`, because `error` is coming from your `store` and you want to show the message when there is a new `error` emitted:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (error !== errorMSG) {
      setERRORS(error);
      alert.show(errorMSG);
    } else {
      alert.show("Welcome!");
    }
  }, [error]);
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! One thing tho I didn't need to use local state, and my error was; not itirating through the object that the state produces.